# Induced current by changing magnetic field and resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, electromagnetic-induction

Let's say we have a wire loop with resistance $R$ in a changing magnetic field. The changing field will induce an electric field and hence an emf $\mathcal{E}$ around the loop. The induced E-field is not conservative and we cannot assign an electric potential. Why then can we calculate the induced current using $\mathcal{E}=IR$ if $R$ is defined to be the ratio between the potential drop and the current? I have read [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112297/induced-potential-difference-in-loop-how-do-voltmeters-work), but I think charges only accumulate to create a potential when the circuit is incomplete, why can we assume that we can say the same thing even if the loop is closed?

Comment: Potential drop is a loose term indicating emf drop over a resitance. It has nothing to do with the potential we associate with conservative fields.